# Import RSA Keys - Unable to find the specified file

Tags: rsa

I am trying to import an RSA Key.
I open cmd prompt in Admin mode, go to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 and my command is as follows: aspnet_regiis - pi "Key" "S:\RSAKeys\Key.xml" -pku

This is the exact same command that my coworker used and it worked perfectly for him. When I try it though, I get "Importing RSA Keys from file..Unable to find the specified file. Failed!"

What could be different between our machines?

I have also tried different things (removing the -pku, trying it not as admin, etc.) but in the end it doesn't fully work.

Trying it not as admin with -pku will say succeeded (but then when I try to use the service, it errors with "The RSA key container could not be opened"). Trying it not as admin without -pku will error with "Access is denied."

Edit 1: Looks like a read perms issue between S drive and C drive maybe. Putting the file on the C drive was able to succeed the import but still receiving an error from the service that uses the import saying the rsa key container could not be opened.

Final Edit: After some research, I discovered that I needed to change permissions. I used these documents to help: https://serverfault.com/questions/293416/the-rsa-key-container-could-not-be-opened-windows-server-2008-r2 http://austrianalex.com/rsaprotectedconfigurationprovider-not-recommended-for-children-under-5.html [The RSA key container could not be opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921589/the-rsa-key-container-could-not-be-opened)

Unfortunately, none of them fixed the problem. Somehow, the RSA key was imported where even the Admin group didn't have the permissions it needed to change permissions. So I went and found the RSA key under the C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys folder. I had originally tried giving the Administrator group (which was only me anyways) full permissions but received a Safe Handle Error and had to remove that.

Finally, I added myself (not the administrator group) with full permissions and it worked. Thanks @Thymine for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: What happens if you do `dir S:\RSAKeys\ ` in the admin cmd prompt?

Comment: So it says The system cannot find the path specified. That gives me the idea maybe it's some read perm issue between S drive and C drive so I tried copying and pasting the file into my C drive and tried again using that file. It says succeeded.
Except, even though it says succeeded, I still get "The RSA key container could not be opened" when I run the service that uses the RSA key file.

Comment: Yeah either permission or the drive might not be mapped for your admin user, can you even `cd S:` in the cmd prompt?

Comment: Hah, no, I can't. System says it can't find the drive.