# Encrypting the Connection String error The RSA key container could not be opened

Tags: asp.net

I am using entity framework database first approach .I have connection string in my config file how can I encrypt my connection string and then how can I decrypt for entity framework
i used aspnet_regiis.exe but I get this error (The RSA key container could not be opened.) when I run software

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework Encrypt Connection String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335413/entity-framework-encrypt-connection-string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The RSA key container could not be opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921589/the-rsa-key-container-could-not-be-opened)